# ¿Como crear una notificación web al detectar actividad en la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Hola estoy intentando crear notificaciones web como las que utiliza `web.whatsapp` o `gmail` cuando recibimos algun mensaje, ya cree la notificacion pero ¿como puedo hacer que la envie cada vez que detecte un nuevo registro en mi base de datos?

Mi notificación en la siguiente:

```
if (Notification) {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
        Notification.requestPermission()
    }
    var title = "titulo"
    var extra = {
        icon: "logo",
        body: "Notificación de prueba"
    }
    var noti = new Notification(title, extra)
    noti.onclick = {

    }
    noti.onclose = {

    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        noti.close()
    }, 10000)
} else {
    Notification.requestPermission()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un `Interval` que vaya chequeando tu `bd`:

```
var registrosBD = 5;// variable global para almacenar los registros actuales

var llamada_ajax= function() {

   //checkear la base de datos
   //un select count(*) From "resto de tu instruccion sql" , 
   //recoges el valor en una variable como registrosAhora, por ejemplo.

    if ( registrosAhora > registrosBD ){

        registrosBD =  registrosAhora;

        //aqui tu codigo de arriba

    }
};

var intervalo = 1000; //milisegundos
setInterval(llamada_ajax, intervalo);
```